# What part of zk blockchain is private?

Tags: zksnark, zero-knowledge, zksync

What part of a ZK blockchain is private?
Let's say for example starknet or zksync, both of them use ZK technology.
If I execute a transaction and I send a native coin (none of them have it yet) anybody can see from who that coin comes and where it goes?

How about interacting with a contract, if I use `transfer` function from an ERC20 token, what part of that transaction will be private ?

Comment: You have to clarify what you mean by "zk blockchain". There are many different kinds of zero-knowledge proof systems.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg In this case I am refering to chains that support smart contracts, not just the transfer or coins like zcash.